How to make HuggingFace LLMs run faster
I am using a LLM as part of my project, the model I am using is Llama 3.1 8B with fp16, I tried to test the model's performance in colab notebook, here is the parameters and it was set to the most common settings for these models.
model = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
"text-generation",
model=model,
tokenizer=tokenizer,
torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
trust_remote_code=True,
device_map="auto",
max_length=1000,
do_sample=True,
top_k=10,
num_return_sequences=1,
eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id
)

The issue is when I try to get a generated text for my question, it takes eternity to run, around 11 mins for the user prompt "what is life?", and when I use a vector store it is much slower, which is too much time for the application I am building and I am not finding any solution outside, and I also new to this field.
I am using colab's T4 15 GB GPU, which is almost enough I thought for this model...
I want this to run fast like within 2 minutes atleast...

if you want to use llm in product, may be it's better to serve it by some tools like lmdeploy or vllm.
these tools deploy llms very efficient and they can answer to request parallel depends on your hardware.

what about ollama?

for local usage it's good but as i know it has not have continues batching.
vLLM and Lmdeploy are more faster.

Ok I will try those.!
